# hide() to show() with content slider

Tags: jquery, slider, hide, show

i'm a new in stackoverflow and this is my first post.
I am trying to get hide() to show() to work on multiple objects but I am unable to get it to work with a content slider (liquid slider).
http://www.alfonsocarmelo.it/margherita/index10.html
when load website, it's possible view a slider (camera slider), but, when i click on "architettura" on the bottom left, and then click "centro culturale - Expo' Flussi di eVenti, Catania" should view a content slider (image and text) with liquid slider script. The script work perfect alone, but in the website have a problem; it's visible narrow, whereas the perfect view is with a width of 100% of the viewport.

HTML

```
<div id="architettura">
    <div class="content">
       <h4><span>A</span>rchitettura<span>/</span></h4>
       <img src="images/architettura/architettura.jpg">  
    </div>
 </div>
 
 <!-- architettura_centro_culturale_catania--> 
 <div id="architettura_centro_culturale_catania">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="liquid-slider"  id="slider-id">
                <div>
                  <h2 class="title">1</h2>

                   <div class="immagini">
                      <img src="images/pittura_02.jpg"> <!-- ELIMINAZIONE DIV E METTERE X OGNI FOTO align="left" width="60%" height="36%"-->
                      <img src="images/pittura_03.jpg">
                      <img src="images/pittura_04.jpg">
                   </div>

                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudindasdas</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h2 class="title">2</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
                </div>          
                <div>
                  <h2 class="title">3</h2>
                  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h2 class="title">4</h2>
                  <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
                </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Liquid Slider Ends Here -->

      
    </div> 
    <!-- end content -->
 </div>
 <!-- end architettura_centro_culturale_catania--> 
  
 <!-- architettura_centro_culturale_giarre--> 
 <div id="architettura_centro_culturale_giarre"></div>
 <!-- end centro culturale Giarre -->
 
 <div id="slideshow">
    <div class="content">
          <div class="fluid_container">
          
              <div class="camera_wrap camera_magenta_skin" id="camera_wrap_1">
              
                <div data-src="images/slides/prova3_modificata.jpg">
               
                    <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                        pittura <span>/</span> LA RICCHEZZA INTERIORE
                    </div>

                </div>
               
                <div data-src="images/slides/prova4_modificata.jpg">
                    <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                        architettura <span>/</span> MUSEO D&acute;ARTE CONTEMPORANEA E CENTRO POLIFUNZIONALE
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
        
            </div> <!-- #camera_wrap_1 -->

          </div> <!-- .fluid_container  -->
    </div>
</div>
    
    
</section>

<footer>
 <nav>
    <ul id="fmenu">
        <li>
         <a href="#" id="idarchitettura"><span>a</span>rchitettura</a>
            <ul id="fmenu_architettura">
                <li id="centro_culturale_catania"><a href="#">centro culturale - Expo' Flussi di eVenti, Catania </a></li>
                <li id="centro_culturale_giarre"><a href="#">centro culturale, Giarre</a></li>
            </ul>  
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#" id="idpittura"><span>p</span>ittura</a>
            <ul id="fmenu_pittura">
                <li id="la_ricchezza_interiore"><a href="#">la ricchezza interiore</a></li>
                <li id="trattenuta_da_1_sentimento"><a href="#">trattenuta da un sentimento</a></li>
                <li id="il_bacio"><a href="#">il bacio</a></li>
                <li id="sguardo_ignoto"><a href="#">sguardo all&acute;Ignoto</a></li>
                <li id="kolorimmersi"><a href="#">kolorimmersi</a></li>    
                <li id="gli_amanti"><a href="#">gli Amanti</a></li>
                <li id="la_danzatrice"><a href="#">la danza(U)trice</a></li>
                <li id="lottare_senza_mani_senza_piedi"><a href="#">lottare senza mani e senza piedi</a></li>
                <li id="kolorinaere"><a href="#">kolorinaere</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#" id="iddesign"><span>d</span>esign</a>
            <ul id="fmenu_design">
                <li id="borse_accessori"><a href="#">borse e accessori</a></li>
                <li id="monili"><a href="#">monili</a></li>
                <li id="oggetti_arredo"><a href="#">oggetti d&acute;arredo</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
        <li id="pubblication"><a href="#"><span>p</span>ubblicazioni</a></li>
        <li id="profile"><a href="#"><span>p</span>rofilo</a></li>
    </ul>        
 </nav>
    </footer>
```

JQUERY CODE

```
   $('#idarchitettura').click(function() { 
              
              $('#slideshow').hide();

              $('#architettura_centro_culturale_catania').hide();
              $('#architettura_centro_culturale_giarre').hide(); 
              $('#pittura').hide();
              $('#pittura_la_ricchezza_interiore').hide();  
              $('#pittura_trattenuta_da_1_sentimento').hide(); 
              $('#pittura_il_bacio').hide(); 
              $('#pittura_sguardo_ignoto').hide();  
              $('#pittura_kolorimmersi').hide(); 
              $('#pittura_gli_amanti').hide(); 
              $('#pittura_la_danzatrice').hide();
              $('#pittura_lottare_senza_mani_senza_piedi').hide();
              $('#pittura_kolorinaere').hide();
              $('#profilo').hide();
              $('#pubblicazioni').hide();
              $('#design').hide();
              $('#design_borse_accessori').hide();
              $('#design_monili').hide();
              $('#design_oggetti_arredo').hide();
        
              $('#architettura').fadeIn('slow');

              /*for menu'*/
              $('#fmenu_architettura').slideToggle();
              $('#fmenu_pittura').slideUp('fast');
              $('#fmenu_design').slideUp('fast');
        }); 
        
        $('#centro_culturale_catania').click(function() {
              
              $('#pubblicazioni').hide();
              $('#profilo').hide(); 
              $('#architettura').hide();
              $('#architettura_centro_culturale_giarre').hide(); 
              $('#pittura').hide(); 
              $('#pittura_la_ricchezza_interiore').hide(); 
              $('#pittura_trattenuta_da_1_sentimento').hide(); 
              $('#pittura_sguardo_ignoto').hide();
              $('#pittura_il_bacio').hide();    
              $('#pittura_kolorimmersi').hide();   
              $('#pittura_gli_amanti').hide(); 
              $('#pittura_la_danzatrice').hide();
              $('#pittura_lottare_senza_mani_senza_piedi').hide();
              $('#pittura_kolorinaere').hide();
              $('#design').hide();
              $('#design_borse_accessori').hide();
              $('#design_monili').hide();
              $('#design_oggetti_arredo').hide();
    
              $('#architettura_centro_culturale_catania').fadeIn('slow');
        });

    });
```

I try another slider script, but, i have the same problem, so i think that there's a problem with hide() to show() with slider script..

Answer (score 0):

Alfonso, implementation must be wrong. I'm sure the .js code you're sharing is not part of the plugin's implementation. Also, I don't quite understand why you're hiding all those divs using individual IDs. Even if you really need all those IDs, I would add a class to hide them all at once (will make the code run a lot faster). Ex.: if you change all those IDs to a class="toHide", or add that class, instead of all those lines, you can simply use:

```
$('.toHide').hide();
```

And boom. Everything will work the same. [I recommend you double-check how you should be using your slider plugin](http://liquidslider.kevinbatdorf.com/category/tutorials/).

Comment: i put a more simple versione of website, the problem still exist...js code i'm sharing is not part of the plugin's implementation, but my jQuery implementation is very simple..for the class, i'm agree with you, but the problem persist..
what's wrong?

Comment: Jquery now:
$('#idarchitettura').click(function() { 
       $('#slideshow').hide();  
       $('#architettura').fadeIn('slow');
}); 
$('#centro_culturale_catania').click(function() {
       $('#slideshow').hide();
       $('#architettura').hide();          $('#architettura_centro_culturale_catania').fadeIn('slow');
});

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you only need to "hide" or "show" some objects on click, you'll have to change your code a bit. You should add a class="className" to each one of your li items (and you can do it via jQuery too). Then, call it with $('.className').hide(); You're still using '#', but # is for IDs. If you're using classes, you should use the dot (.) instead.

Comment: sorry, i use a simple versione of website: http://www.alfonsocarmelo.it/margherita/index10.html if i click in this link "centro culturale - Expo Flussi di eVenti, Catania" the slider not show well..you understand me now?it isn't a class problem..

Comment: sorry for my basic jquery language, i add the code above in my website, but nothing....doesn't function..

$('#slider-id').liquidSlider({
 dynamicTabsPosition: 'bottom',
 dynamicTabsAlign: 'right',
 panelTitleSelector: 'h2.title',
 hoverArrows: false
});
     
var sliderObject = $.data( $('#slider-id')[0], 'liquidSlider');
console.log(sliderObject); 
sliderObject.adjustHeight();
});


 
$('#centro_culturale_catania').click(function() {     
 $('#prova').fadeIn('slow');
 adjustHeight();
});

});

Comment: Check @Kevin's answer and see if it helps. I hope it does. I saw that page and the problem. It could be a CSS problem. For now, that specific page seems to be down for me...

Comment: i contact kevin directly..i don't know what's the problem..the page http://www.alfonsocarmelo.it/margherita/index10.html now is up, there were hosting problem..

Answer (score 0):

7th is right in that you shouldn't hide your elements separately like that. It may cause a performance issue and it's also just sloppy code.

However, about your problem with the [Liquid Slider](http://liquidslider.kevinbatdorf.com), it's happening because the slider doesn't know the height of your panels (because they are hidden).

If you look in your DOM tree, you see:

```
<div class="liquid-slider" id="slider-id" style="height: 0px;">
```

Notice the height is 0?

The [Liquid Slider](http://liquidslider.kevinbatdorf.com) lets you access most of the internal functions. You first have to set the slider as an object, then you can adjust the height. I imagine you could add the `adjustHeight()` method on the click event that shows the slider. Try it out and see.

```
var sliderObject = $.data( $('#slider-id')[0], 'liquidSlider');

sliderObject.adjustHeight();
```